# Regex replacing the first character in a group

Tags: regex

Apologies, I've tried - and it might just be me being a bit dense, but I just can't get my head around it.

I've got some data in a format similar to:

```
Some Text L1234
Some Other Text L5587
```

I need to replace the L in the final group to be an A (it's always Ldddd at the end).

```
(L[0-9]{4})
```

to find the group was as far as I got, I've no idea how to then replace the L!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: What OS/editor/RDBMS/etc are you doing this in? Where does the data reside, in a file? variable? column?  How many will be operated on at a time? Not all regular expression engines are created equal.

Comment: use ([\w].*)(L)(\d{4}$) regex to find the matching characters and \1A\3 to replace L with A

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this regex,

```
L(?=\d{4}$)
```

and replace it with 'A'

This look ahead `(?=\d{4}$)` makes sure, only `L` is selected for replacement which is followed by exactly 4 digits and end of string.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WeFAwq/1)**

Comment: Thanks so much - makes complete sense, I just couldn't get my head around it when I was staring at the documentation!

Comment: Glad, I could help :)